# Javascript display for loop based on user input values

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a website page that has two textboxes and a submit button. The first is for the starting number, the second is for the ending number. I want to print all the values between the two values into a paragraph tag when the user clicks a submit button. Example. Textbox 1 = 5, Textbox 2 = 15, tag = 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15.

I got it to work to my needs in a C# Console App with a FizzBuzz style to it:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
 int start;
 int end;

 Console.WriteLine("Enter number for starting range");
 start = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
 Console.WriteLine("Enter number for ending range");
 end = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

 for(int i = start; i <= end; i++)
  {
   if(i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0)
    {
     Console.WriteLine("FizzBuzz");
    }
   else if(i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 != 0)
    {
     Console.WriteLine("Fizz");
    }
   else if(i % 3 != 0 && i % 5 == 0)
    {
     Console.WriteLine("Buzz");
    }
   else
    {
     Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
  }
}
```

My question is how can I do this using JavaScript?
Here is my non-working code:

```
<p>Fizzy</p>
<input type="text" id="start"/>
<input type="text" id="end"/>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Test Me</button>
<p id="result"></p> <-I WANT TO DISPLAY NUMBERS INSIDE THIS TAG

<script type="text/javascript">
 function myFunction() {
  var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
  var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
  var i;

  for(i = start; i <= end; i++)
   {
    if(i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0)
      //Display number as "FizzBuzz"
    else if(i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 != 0)
      //Display number as "Fizz"
    else if( i % 3 != 0 && i % 5 == 0)
      //Display number as "Buzz"
    else
      //Display number
  }
   //I want to assign the "value of the loop" to result
   // "loop result" = document.getElementById("result");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please change both your C# and JS code samples to have proper indentation - it makes them much easier to read.

Comment: I believe that `start` and `end` are strings, turn them into numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build a string in the loop using basic string concatenation and then set that string as HTML of the `#result` element.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
  var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
  var i;
  var el = document.getElementById("result");
  var output = "";
  for (i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0){
      output += 'FizzBuzz ';
    }
      //Display number as "FizzBuzz"
    else if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 != 0){
      output += 'Fizz ';
    }
    else if (i % 3 != 0 && i % 5 == 0){
      output += 'Buzz ';
    }
    else{
      output += i+' ';      
    }
  }
  
  el.innerHTML = output;
}
```

```html
<p>Fizzy</p>
<input type="text" id="start" />
<input type="text" id="end" />
<button onclick="myFunction()">Test Me</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```